# Session expiring in Yii2 despite user activity

Tags: session, yii2

I have started using Yii2 and need to store more information about user in identity. I already know that in Yii2, this should be done using sessions like

```
Yii::$app->session->set('user.company_id', '121');
```

This works fine as I am able to get these values later in project using:

```
Yii::$app->session->get('user.company_id');
```

. However, these session values are getting wiped up despite user activity on same pages. So after 5-10 minutes, the same user sees some fields based on session value, however, after 1 minute if I refresh the session values go away which should actually happen on session close or user logout.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use the default Yii2  User component?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this? We are facing the same issue, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of solid information (apart from [this ticket](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5880) ).

Answer (score 2):

First check your `app\config\main.php` or `main-local.php` if it contains:

```
'user' => [
    ...
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ...
],
```

Second check if you have a proper assignment to the value assigned to the variable:

```
$authTimeout;
$absoluteAuthTimeout;
```

See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) for more.

Comment: Doc [says](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$authTimeout-detail) that  `$authTimeout` & `$absoluteAuthTimeout` will not work if `$enableAutoLogin` is `true`.

Comment: @letsjump...   i have read...(i don't know if the docs is changed in the last year ) .  but for me work as aspected  ..